# Laravel5: ID output is not available in laravel5

Tags: laravel, laravel-authorization

ID output is not available in laravel5.

### 1. fail

```
dd(Auth::User()->id)
```

output : 0

### 2. success

```
dd(Auth::User()->email)
```

output : test@naver.com

Everything else works well. id is not printing.

### try

app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php

```
public function username(){
    return 'id';
}
```

### users migration

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('xid');
        $table->string('platform')->default('site'); 
        $table->smallInteger('level')->default('0'); 
        $table->string('id')->unique();
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password'); 
        $table->string('name'); 
        $table->string('school_name');
        $table->string('school_code'); 
        $table->integer('money')->default('0'); 
        $table->smallInteger('access')->default('0'); 
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->integer('buy_count')->default('0'); 
        $table->integer('law_count')->default('0'); 
        $table->rememberToken(); 
        $table->timestamps(); });
```

### User Model

```
 protected $fillable = [
    'school_name','school_code','name', 'id', 'password','phone'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
```

### dd result

```
#original: array:16 [▼
"xid" => 1
"platform" => "site"
"level" => 2
"id" => "testid"
"email" => "test@naver.com"
"password" => "$2y$10$exeC0AGystAtLI3mdFbdYu1aWzGc6GEv/12DnMjjqCHKABqM2DfSO"
"name" => "test"
"school_name" => "test"
"school_code" => "S010000599"
"money" => 0
"access" => 1
"phone" => "01011112222"
"buy_count" => 0
"law_count" => 0
"remember_token" => "KQvgIRjp35Y9RA8hY1K2b7zMbnnk0gTFO3x1k8SIkPq4dwXoG98cAOnv4ViZ"
"created_at" => "2018-02-21 14:06:26"
"updated_at" => "2018-02-24 22:43:51"
```

Comment: show us dd(Auth::user())

Comment: dd(Auth::id()) try this

Comment: @Jigs1212 I tried. It's not possible.

Comment: @Sohel0415 The output is fine.

Comment: as mentioned above show us dd(Auth::user())

Comment: @MingeunKim is `id` is your primary key for `User` Model?

Comment: did u check the database what should be the actual output ?
That is what is the id ?

Comment: Is id set has as a hidden attribute in the user model?

Comment: @btl nope. It is set to fillable.

Comment: @Jigs1212 yes. database show output

Comment: @laravellevaral set to fillable.

Comment: what is the id filed name in the database ?

Comment: @MingeunKim id should be the primary key and not to be set as fillable usually..

Comment: The field name is id.

Comment: in database the id has values other than 0 ??

Comment: The id value in the database is 'test'

Comment: Even if it is not fillable, it does not output successfully.

Comment: The user model and users db migration have been added to the body.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `id()` method:

```
auth()->id()
```

Or:

```
\Auth::id()
```

Comment: The way you have noticed is that 0 is the output.

Comment: @MingeunKim please show all the data available if you want to get help. Show the result of `dd(auth()->user());`. Show the `users` table migration file and the data from DB table. It's impossible to help you without the info.

Comment: The user model and users db migration have been added to the body.

Comment: @MingeunKim you haven't added unfolded result of `dd(auth()->user());`

Comment: Added. Please check. Thank you.

Comment: @MingeunKim thank you. Could you also show full use model as is?

Comment: Are you saying user.php?

Comment: @MingeunKim yes.

Comment: @MingeunKim you've just added `User.php` without model class contents.

Comment: [click link](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/User.php) It's the same as the code for that url.

Comment: @MingeunKim it really looks like the model was modified but if you're saying it wasn't, I can't help. If the model wasn't modified in any way, the `auth()->user()->id` should work.

Comment: The model has not been modified. I did not touch the fillable except for adding an id. But the output is not normal.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this

```
Auth::user()->id
```